Does $\frac{I + K}{2}\otimes\frac{I+L}{2} = \frac{I+K\otimes L}{2}$ hold for operators $K,L$ acting on different subsystems?
Let's index $i= 1, 2$ be the index representing different systems. A $Z_i$ projective measurement has projectors $P_i = \{ \frac{I+Z_i}{2}, \frac{I-Z_i}{2} \}$. One can verify that the measurement $Z_1\otimes Z_2$ has projectors
$$ \{ \frac{I+Z_1\otimes Z_2}{2}, \frac{I-Z_1\otimes Z_2}{2} \}$$
Is this a general result? Given operators $K$ and $L$ acting on different systems, is
$$\frac{I + K}{2}\otimes\frac{I+L}{2} = \frac{I+K\otimes L}{2}?$$
Does any such result hold even if it's on the same system but where $K$ and $L$ commute?

I realised after typing my answer that you were asking a slightly different question. However, reading your question I'm not sure it makes sense. If you replace $K=Z_1$ and $L=Z_2$, then the property you are asking for doesn't hold.

It is not the case that for observables $K,L$,
$$
\frac{I+K}{2}\otimes\frac{I+L}{2}=\frac{I+K\otimes L}{2}.
$$
However, if $K^2=I$ and $L^2=I$ then
$$
\frac{I+K\otimes L}{2}=\frac{I+K}{2}\otimes\frac{I+L}{2}+\frac{I-K}{2}\otimes\frac{I-L}{2}.
$$
You could check this just by multiplying it out and collecting terms.
What's happening is that you're interested in $+1$ subspaces of observables with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. The $+1$ subspace of the observable $K\otimes L$ could come from the $+1$ subspace of $K$ AND the $+1$ subspace of $L$, or it could come from the $-1$ subspace of both, because when you take a tensor product, eigenvalues multiply.

A question: The second equation is always true but when $K^2 = L^2 = I$, the left hand side is a projector corresponding to an observable, is that right? Now, this observable $K\otimes L$ is expressed as the sum of the tensor product of two projectors on the right hand side?

You should first ask how do you prove the statement for $Z_1$, $Z_2$. Well why is $\frac{I + Z_1}{2}$ a projector?
$$
\left(\frac{I+Z_1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac14(I + 2Z_1 + Z_1^2) = \frac14(2I + 2Z_1) = \frac{I+Z_1}{2}\,,
$$
the key step in the proof is $Z_1^2 = I$, which is not true of all observables! In particular it is only true if the observable has eigenvalues $\pm 1$ (equivalently it represents a measurement with outcomes $\pm 1$.)
This leads us to a general statement. Take any observable $M$ with $\pm 1$ eigenvalues then we can write its projectors as
$$
\left\{\frac{I+M}{2}, \frac{I-M}{2}\right\}. 
$$
Note this extends immediately to tensor product observables also, if $M$ is an observable with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ and $N$ is an observable with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ then so is $M \otimes N$. Thus the above result applies and we have its projectors onto the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenspaces repectively are
$$
\left \{ \frac{I + M \otimes N}{2}, \frac{I - M \otimes N}{2} \right \}
$$
